# Draw graphics inside a UIButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have some (fairly large) UIButtons. Instead of text, I would like to draw some simple colored graphics inside them (lines, boxes).

How can it be done without resorting to using prerendered images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot subclass `UIButton`, you should subclass `UIView` and implement the `drawRect:` method. Then, add this to your `UIButton` as a subview.